# Redoc side menu

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, openapi, redoc

I want to use Redoc for my API documentation. I also have swagger.

I found here : https://github.com/Redocly/redoc this line - **Integrate API Introduction into side menu - ReDoc takes advantage of markdown headings from OpenAPI description field. It pulls them into side menu and also supports deep linking.**

I want to add my readme file to left side bar in Redoc. But I didn`t find any good example for it. What should I change, where readme should be added?

My redoc setup :

```
app.UseReDoc(c =>
            {
                c.DocumentTitle = $"Documentation";
                c.SpecUrl = /api/docs/swagger.json";
                c.RoutePrefix = "docs";
            });
```

Comment: i found a relevant answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54305473/3131504

Answer (score 1):

That documentation is referring to the `info.description` field.

You can embed the readme into the API definition like this:

```
info:
  description:
     $ref: ./path/to/readme.md
```

Replace that path with your actual path to the readme.

---

Source: https://redoc.ly/docs/api-reference-docs/embedded-markdown/#embedded-markdown-in-redocly-api-reference-docs

Note: If you are unable to change the API description, you could do it in post-processing using OpenAPI CLI and a custom decorator with the `bundle` command.

Comment: Which file I need to change? Is it should be auto generated file by swagger?

Comment: I have .net core 3.1 project